Capacities of a MT-49 MIDI keyboard
I recently got this MT-49 MIDI Keyboard that I want to use as a controller inside softwares such as FL Studio.
But I was wondering, as it only has one MIDI output (MIDI out only, no MIDI in, and no audio output), why does it have also a wide selection of programs (different instruments such as pianos, guitars, organs, ...) ? From what I understood, MIDI signal does not control this kind of things, right ?
Maybe I'm not using it the right way so I wonder if anyone can help me understanding how to use it, and if it is actually possible to use the instruments the keyboard seems to offer inside softwares like FL studio.
Currently, it only works as a basic controller using a MIDI/USB inside FL Studio. Here is the manual as well : https://miditech.de/download/mt-49-english/?tmstv=1731267833
Thank you !

From what I understood, MIDI signal does not control this kind of things, right ? Wrong. There is a list of various commands which can be send via MIDI, see e.g. this reference: https://midi.org/summary-of-midi-1-0-messages How this commands are interpreted (or whether they are interpreted or ignored) depends on the receiving device or software.


why does it have also a wide selection of programs

Because it doesn't.
That list is there just as a convenience to the user, and is based on the General MIDI standard.
That keyboard does not offer any sound, because that's not how MIDI works.
The MIDI standard is based on messages (events) that are normally made of very small numeric sequences (usually up to 4 numbers).
A MIDI event does not (nor can) contain any "sound" or "preset"[see note]: it's just a short number sequence that is interpreted by what receives it. It's not that different from an electric switch, because its effect only depends on what is connected to it: it doesn't transmit "light" just because it's connected to a light bulb.
One of the many event types MIDI provides is the program change event, which, like most MIDI events, has a value in the 0-127 range (even though they are often listed using the 1-128 range).
That value is just a number, without any specific meaning: how that event is eventually handled depends on the connected devices. It just "tells": "please change to program 12".
The receiving device may even ignore that event, or "change the sound" (aka, the patch) to a specific sound assigned to that number.
If that device is compliant to the General MIDI specification, then the resulting sound will theoretically resemble the description: for instance, 0 for an "Acoustig Grand Piano", 56 for a trumpet, etc. But that's just because that device has been built to associate specific numbers to those sounds.
In reality, that sound list is only followed by general purpose keyboards and old MIDI expanders, some old computer sound cards, computer systems that provide such a feature natively (Windows) and some "sound fonts" that can be installed on players and DAWs.
Even with devices that followed that standard, the list wasn't always consistent, and some manufacturers or models changed theirs sounds to some extent, also depending on the target of the device.
Most MIDI devices have an internal sound bank, and even if they provide 0-127 range based "programs", the actual sounds are quite different than that list.
For instance, synthesizers are obviously unable to reproduce so many different and specific sounds, so that list is clearly pointless in that case. It's up to their users to organize those banks and eventually keep a list of the program numbers when they need to switch patches.
As another example, the E-mu Proteus/2 (Orchestral) sound module only has string instruments at the beginning of their preset list. Actually, that module provides more than 128 "sounds", and it can be configured in order to associate specific program changes to any of them: by default, 0 corresponds to a "Solo Cello", but it can be configured to associate, for example, the trumpet (39) to program 0.
DAWs are normally able to react to specific MIDI events, and some allow further customization: in some cases, they can be configured so that when receiving a specific program change they may do something completely unrelated.
Note: it is possible to send audio data, but not as you may think; MIDI provides "sys-ex" messages that allow to send any kind of data to a device that is able to interpret it, and some devices allow sending or receiving audio sampled "patches"; yet, MIDI is very slow (~30kB per second) so it's only intended for backup, maintenance or system updates, not for live playing.

Thanks you for this very exhaustive answer !

@MatthieuSouda You're very welcome! Remember that if an answer solves your issue you should mark it as accepted by checking the grey tick on its left.
